# Swift Failable Initializers - Unable to get my code working

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, option-type

I'm struggling to understand why my code isn't working? Any help/correction is appreciated.

```
struct DogBowlWithFailableInitializers {
    var foodLeft: Int
    init?(foodLeft: Int) {
        if foodLeft < 0 {
            return nil
        }
        self.foodLeft = foodLeft
    }
}

if let negativeDogFoodTest = DogBowlWithFailableInitializers(foodLeft: 10) {
    print("Success!")
    let negativeDogFoodTest = DogBowlWithFailableInitializers(foodLeft: 10)
}
else {
    print("Invalid dog food amount inputted")
}
```

From my understanding, a new instance should be created since it passed both if statements inside the structure and out. But when I try to access any properties within the instance, I'm not able to, why is that?

```
print(negativeDogFoodTest.foodLeft) //doesn't work
```

Comment: and where did you call the print?

Comment: Are you referring to print(negativeDogFoodTest.foodLeft)? It was called outside the entire block of code.

Comment: Dont know what's your problem? The code work fine, why do you call `let negativeDogFoodTest` again in the success code?

Comment: but that print won't even execute from outside that block as there is global variable negativeDogFoodTest ? @Noodles

Comment: I added let negativeDogFoodTest in the success code to see if it might fix the issue, it didn't (my mistake, I should've removed it before posting). I'm still unable to access any of it's properties and I've noticed Xcode doesn't help me autofill "negativeDogFoodTest" as well. 
@Fay077 I'm sorry, I don't understand. print(negativeDogFoodTest.foodLeft) is directly underneath the last curly bracket of the else statement.

Comment: "doesn't work" is *not* a reasonable issue description. The compiler gives you a specific error message. Read it, try to understand it, share it.

Comment: @Raphael You're right, I'll be sure to include the error message next time. 
Sweepers response helped me, thank you everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to understand the concept of *scoping*. Consider this simple if let statement:

```
if let x = y {
    // A
    someVariable = x // works
}
// B
someVariable = x // does not work
```

`x` is only accessible inside the if statement, i.e. at `A`. Outside the if statement, i.e. at `B`, `x` is *out of scope*.

Why? Because it makes no sense to access `x` at `B` because `B` is executed whether or not `y` is nil.

So you should access it inside the if statement.

Another problem is that you declared `negativeDogFoodTest` twice:

```
// 1st time
if let negativeDogFoodTest = DogBowlWithFailableInitializers(foodLeft: 10) {
    print("Success!")
    // 2nd time!
    let negativeDogFoodTest = DogBowlWithFailableInitializers(foodLeft: 10)
}
```

One time is enough!

```
if let negativeDogFoodTest = DogBowlWithFailableInitializers(foodLeft: 10) {
    print("Success!")
    print(negativeDogFoodTest.foodleft)
}
```

You can also consider a guard statement:

```
guard let negativeDogFoodTest = DogBowlWithFailableInitializers(foodLeft: 10) 
    else { return }
```

Answer (score 0):

`negativeDogFoodTest` is a local variable with scope in the `then`-branch of your `if`. It does not exist outside of that block.

So you need to do this:

```
if let negativeDogFoodTest = ... {
    print(negativeDogFoodTest.foodLeft)
}
```

Note that your second assignment to `negativeDogFoodTest` is redundant.

You can also use `guard` instead:

```
guard let negativeDogFoodTest = ... else {
    dealWithFailure()
    (return|break|continue)
}

print(negativeDogFoodTest.foodLeft)
```